# Read updated environment variables in python

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, hpc

I am trying to create a python3 script that runs on an HPC cluster. The purpose of this script is to set up an environment for running simulations afterwards. Therefore various data-pre-processing activities are needed. As there are several versions of the simulation software installed via modules on the cluster, the idea is to load the respective module (software version) within the python script via:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('module load hpcmodule',shell=True).wait()
subprocess.Popen('executablefromhpcmodule.exe')
```

The `module load` command basically updates various system variables, that are needed by the executables afterwards. Also, there might be various calls to executables from the module within the script. So, combining the two commands shown above to one does not work for me. How can I get the updated system variables  from the system after loading the module. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is to use wrapper script. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

MODULE=$1
EXEC=$2

module load $MODULE
eval $EXEC
```

Then, you could use it like this:

`subprocess.call(["wrapper.sh", "hpcmodule", "executablefromhpcmodule.exe"])`